# Different DropDownList Selected value for the same EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that has the following:

```
<div>
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone1)
</div>
<div>
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone2)
</div>
<div>
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone3)
</div>
```

Each of these fields is an instance of the Phone class. In the EditorTemplate for Phone I have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PhoneTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn"})
```

In the controller I have:

```
ViewBag.PhoneTypeID = new SelectList(db.PhoneTypes, "PhoneTypeID", "Type", PhoneTypeIDValue);
```

Right now, each of the three is getting the same selected value in the dropdown list because they are using the same SelectList object.

Is there a way I can give each of these three dropdowns a different selected value when I populate them from the controller and use the same editorTemplate?

Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
ViewBag.Phone1.PhoneTypeID = new SelectList(db.PhoneTypes, "PhoneTypeID", "Type", Phone1.PhoneTypeIDValue);
ViewBag.Phone2.PhoneTypeID = new SelectList(db.PhoneTypes, "PhoneTypeID", "Type", Phone2.PhoneTypeIDValue);
ViewBag.Phone3.PhoneTypeID = new SelectList(db.PhoneTypes, "PhoneTypeID", "Type", Phone3.PhoneTypeIDValue);
```

However, when I do that I get the error:

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: You can write `new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "" }`;

Comment: What do you mean "different selected value when I populate them"?

Comment: @Hadee When the view is rendered, each dropdown should have a different selected value

Comment: The list also should be different for each dropdown?

Comment: No the list is the same, just which option is selected is different

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is you method. Change

```
ViewBag.Phone1.PhoneTypeID = new SelectList(db.PhoneTypes, "PhoneTypeID", "Type", Phone1.PhoneTypeIDValue);
```

To:

```
var phoneTypes = db.PhoneTypes!= null ? db.PhoneTypes.Select(phoneType=> new { PhoneTypeID= phoneType.Id, Type= phoneType.type }) : null;
 ViewBag.PhoneType1 = phoneTypes != null ? new SelectList(phoneTypes , "PhoneTypeID", "Type", phoneTypes.PhoneTypeIDValue) : null;
```

Change `phoneType.Id` and `phoneType.type`  to proper names based on your `phoneTypes` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your common `SelectList` to the `EditorTemplate` using `aditionalViewData` (the second parameter of `EditorFor()`)

In the GET method, generate the `SelectList` using

```
ViewBag.PhoneTypeList = new SelectList(db.PhoneTypes, "PhoneTypeID", "Type");
```

Note that the name of the property should not be the same as the property your binding to (if it is, you lose client side validation), and the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` is ignored when binding to a model property.

Then the code in the main view should be

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Phone1, new { phonelist = ViewBag.PhoneTypeList })
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Phone2, new { phonelist = ViewBag.PhoneTypeList })
```

and in the `EditorTemplate`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PhoneTypeID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["phonelist "]), new { @class = "btn" })
```

The correct option in each dropdownlist will now be selected based on the value of the `PhoneTypeID` property.

Note that the preferred approach is to use view models containing a property for the `SelectList` rather than using `ViewBag`

Answer (score -1):

I wound up just doing this in javascript. I put the values in TempData and then on the view I look at tempdata to set the values, so it looks like the following:

Controller:

```
ViewBag.PhoneTypeID = new SelectList(db.PhoneTypes, "PhoneTypeID", "Type");
if(model.Phone1 != null)
{
   TempData["Phone1Type"] = model.Phone1.PhoneTypeID;
}
if (model.Phone2 != null)
{
    TempData["Phone2Type"] = model.Phone2.PhoneTypeID;
}
```

View:

```
<div>
  <div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone1)
  </div>
  <div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone2)
  </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ('@TempData["Phone1Type"]' != "") {
            document.getElementById("Phone1_PhoneTypeID").selectedIndex = @TempData["Phone1Type"];
        }
        if ('@TempData["Phone2Type"]' != "") {
            document.getElementById("Phone2_PhoneTypeID").selectedIndex = @TempData["Phone2Type"];
        }
    });
</script>
}
```

Hope that helps!